# I want to remove id from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to remove in CodeIgniter http://localhost/papa/plan?id=5
**My current URL is**
http://localhost/papa/plan?id=5

http://localhost/papa= is the base URL

I want my url should be like http://localhost/papa/plan/id/5

Comment: If I understand you would convert from dynamic address to static one.  You have to enable URL rewriting.  If you are using Apache you can use mod_rewrite module. You should modify a .htaccess file (directory level) and insert in it an IfModule tag and a RewriteRule

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your server. A few examples

## Apache

You need to enable `mod_rewrite`. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Then you will need to edit your .htaccess file and write a rule similar to

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

## Nginx

I'm not that well-versed with nginx, but this might be a good read: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Example rewrite rule: rewrite ^/listings/(.*)$ /listing.html?listing=$1 last;

## IIS

I found the following steps:

> Go to IIS Manager.
>
> Select Default Web Site.
>
> In the Feature View click URL Rewrite.
>
> In the Actions pane on the right-hand side, click Add rules…
>
> In the Add Rules dialog box, select Blank Rule and click OK.
>
> Now you must define the actual rewrite rule. In the URL Rewrite Module, a rewrite rule is defined by specifying four required pieces of information:
>
> Name of the rule.
>
> Pattern to use for matching the URL string.
>
> Optional set of conditions.
>
> Action to perform if a pattern is matched and whether all conditions checks succeed.

See this page with screenshots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module